# Plot continuous data with discrete colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I found some similar questions but the answers didn't solve my problem.

I try to plot a time series of to variables as a scatterplot and using the date to color the points. In this example, I created a simple dataset (see below) and I want to plot all data with timesteps in the 1960ties, 70ties, 80ties and 90ties with one colour respectively.

Using the standard plot command (plot(x,y,...)) it works the way it should, as I try using the ggplot library some strange happens, I guess I miss something. Has anyone an idea how to solve this and generate a correct plot?

Here is my code using the standard plot command with a colorbar

```
# generate data frame with test data
x <- seq(1,40)
y <- seq(1,40)
year <- c(rep(seq(1960,1969),2),seq(1970,1989,2),seq(1990,1999))
df <- data.frame(x,y,year)

# define interval and assing color to interval
myinterval <- seq(1959,1999,10)
mycolors <- rainbow(4) 
colbreaks <- findInterval(df$year, vec = myinterval, left.open = T)

# basic plot 
layout(array(1:2,c(1,2)),widths =c(5,1)) # divide the device area in two panels 
par(oma=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(3,3,3,3))
plot(x,y,pch=20,col = mycolors[colbreaks])

# add colorbar
ncols <- length(myinterval)-1
colbarlabs <- seq(1960,2000,10)
par(mar=c(5,0,5,5))
image(t(array(1:ncols, c(ncols,1))), col=mycolors, axes=F)
box()
axis(4, at=seq(0.5/(ncols-1)-1/(ncols-1),1+1/(ncols-1),1/(ncols-1)), labels=colbarlabs, cex.axis=1, las=1) 
abline(h=seq(0.5/(ncols-1),1,1/(ncols-1)))
mtext("year",side=3,line=0.5,cex=1)
```

[image: basics scatter plot with colorbar]

As I would like to use ggplot package, as I do for other plots, I tried this version with ggplot

```
# plot with ggplot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=year)) + geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours= mycolors[colbreaks])
```

[image: plot with ggplot]

but it didn't work the way I thought it would. Obviously, there is something wrong with the color coding. Also, the colorbar looks strange. I also tried it with scale_color_manual and scale_color_gradient2 but I got more errors (Error in continuous_scale).

Any idea how to solve this and generate a plot according to the standard plot [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibyS4.png) including a colorbar.

Comment: You need to use `ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(colbreaks))) + geom_point() +  scale_colour_manual(values = mycolors)`. it would work more consistent if `colbreaks` will be in `df` and `mycolors` should be named `names(mycolors) <- 2:(length(myinterval) - 1) `

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, that works fine. Is there a way to use/plot a classic colorbar, like the one in the plot above?.

Comment: Well, can't think off the top of my head. Best is: `ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = colbreaks)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = mycolors, labels =  seq(1960, 1990, by = 10))`. But why you whant continuous scale to appear as discrete? Honestly, your scale on second picture looks kinda confusing than, why not use a categorical one with '<1970', '<1980' etc.?

Comment: Sorry @Andrey, I guess my question was a little bit misleading. Actually, I don't want a continuous scale, I just want, in this case, four colors in the colorbar. I re-edit my post and added a new image using basic commands with a colorbar.

Comment: This feature has been requested for `ggplot2`, but there are some other walkarounds as you can see here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2673